# Updating Realm objects in a multilayer application

Tags: android, architecture, realm

What's the proper way to getting around realm object manipulation in a multilayer project?

Lets say there's the `PersonStore` that manages the realm objects,
the `PersonEditorView` that edits a `PersonViewModel` and lastly a
`PersonController` that connects the strings. An oversimplified model.

To my way of thinking it goes like this when we want to edit an object.

1. The controller instantiates a ViewModel using the object-to-be-edited
2. Passes that ViewModel to the view
3. The view manages the input from the user and alters the ViewModel, applying the business over the changes (eg constraints, age to be between [0,200], etc).
4. When done tells the controller to persist the object
5. The controller copies the ViewModel fields to the realm object
6. And calls the `PersonStore` to update the object.
7. Everybody's happy :)

But in a realm that doesn't seem to be possible. In step **5** the object cannot be updated `outside a realm transaction`. So the viewmodel-to-model conversion should be performed inside the controller using a `Realm.Transaction` object.
This makes the controller to use realm directly, which is what `PersonStore` should be doing.

Is this how it is done? I'm not interested in how an object is updated in a realm, but how can this be incorporated in an application with many layers.

I'm working on Android but this makes little difference.

Comment: Clearly you want to set up an unmanaged object in the form and then `insertOrUpdate` it to create or update the object in the Realm with the same primary key

Comment: Can you post this as an answer to accept it? Only thing I was missing was the `realm.copyFromRealm()` which creates unmanaged objects.